# Theme does not get applied for list-item layout when using Inflator in ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got a ListView and a custom adapter. I also got a layout for the list-item which gets inflated inside the adapters `getView()`. When I apply a theme to the list-item using `@style/MyStyle` the style does not get applied. However when I use `setTheme(R.style.MyStyle)` after inflating, the style DOES work. This is quite annoying because I would have to programatically apply themes to my controls inside the adapter.

Anyone got a clue why this behaves like it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated(); after to setTheme  ?
for exam.

```
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    listView.setTheme(R.style.MyStyle);

    adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
```